# Appending hostname to path and creating URL

Tags: javascript

Its been long time. I want a small help from Stack Overflow community. I am working on a web application in Oracle Visual Builder which consists of two parts. Below is the overview for it.

URL1: https://www.hostname.com/application/application1

URL2: https://www.hostname.com/application/application2

The host name for both URLs are same and is getting generating after staging the application. Here what I am doing is - with the help of JavaScript function, I am extracting or getting the host name from URL1, storing it in a variable and then appending the host name with '/application/application2'. This makes the URL for application2. Next I stored the URL for application2([www.hostname.com/application/application2](http://www.hostname.com/application/application2)) in another variable(varURL). Now, I have a hyperlink in home page of application1. The hyperlink is defined as

> a id="application2URL" href=" [[ varURL ]] "

The problem here that I am facing is, the URL of application2 is getting appended to URL of application1 at runtime. Like this -

https://www.hostname.com/application/application1/www.hostname.com/application/application2

This logically cannot happen as I am calling JS function only once and my variable contains only the URL for application2 which  is [www.hostname.com/application/application2](http://www.hostname.com/application/application2). Can anyone help me on why is this happening and how can I resolve this issue?

The JS code is below:

```
function() {
   let hostName = window.location.hostname;
   let varURL = hostName + '/application/application2';
   return varURL;
}
```

Comment: could you show us the javascript you have so far?
Also:
`The host name for both URLs are same.`
Here what I am doing is - with the help of JavaScript function, `I am extracting or getting the host name from URL1,` storing it in a variable and then appending the host name with '/application/application2'. 
If the hostnames are the same then why do you look at the hostnames in URL1?

Answer (score 0):

Links in HTML and Javascript need the protocol at the beginning in order to know that the URL is absolute and not relative. Make sure that you add `https://` before the URL for application2.